# Auto Reload for page-limit-bytes and page-limit-messages?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I noticed that `page-limit-bytes` and `page-limit-messages` do not auto-reload on changing its value from `broker.xml`

```xml
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>

            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>
            <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>

            <!-- The size of each page file -->
            <page-size-bytes>1M</page-size-bytes>

            <!-- When we start applying the address-full-policy, e.g paging -->
            <!-- Both are disabled by default, which means we will use the global-max-size/global-max-messages  -->
            <max-size-bytes>1</max-size-bytes>
            <max-size-messages>1</max-size-messages>

            <!-- When we read from paging into queues (memory) -->

            <max-read-page-messages>-1</max-read-page-messages>
            <max-read-page-bytes>20M</max-read-page-bytes>

            <!-- Limit on paging capacity before starting to throw errors -->

            <page-limit-bytes>10M</page-limit-bytes>
            <page-limit-messages>100</page-limit-messages>
            <page-full-policy>FAIL</page-full-policy >
            <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>
          </address-setting>
```

Am I missing something or is this not possible to do?

Also, I didn't find anything related to the same in [Configuration Reload](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/config-reload.html#address-settings)

Using v2.31.2

#### How did I get the issue

The page-limit-message is set to 100, then I can send 100 messages using command

```
./artemis producer --message-size 10 --message-count 100 --user artemis --password artemis
```

And when I hit this command again - got the following error (which is expected)

```
Connection brokerURL = tcp://localhost:61616
Producer ActiveMQQueue[TEST], thread=0 Started to calculate elapsed time ...

javax.jms.JMSException: AMQ229102: Address "TEST" is full.
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:560)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:452)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQSessionContext.sendFullMessage(ActiveMQSessionContext.java:588)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.sendRegularMessage(ClientProducerImpl.java:305)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.doSend(ClientProducerImpl.java:277)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.send(ClientProducerImpl.java:147)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.send(ClientProducerImpl.java:129)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageProducer.doSendx(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:483)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:194)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.messages.ProducerThread.sendMessage(ProducerThread.java:125)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.messages.ProducerThread.run(ProducerThread.java:91)
Caused by: ActiveMQAddressFullException[errorType=ADDRESS_FULL message=AMQ229102: Address "TEST" is full.]
        ... 11 more
```

And when I change page-limit-messages to 1000 I'm getting still same error and number of messages in the queue is still 101.

```xml
<page-limit-messages>1000</page-limit-messages>
```

Cannot see `page-limit` attributes in `getAddressSettingsAsJSON`

```json
{
    "DLA": "DLQ",
    "expiryAddress": "ExpiryQueue",
    "expiryDelay": -1,
    "minExpiryDelay": -1,
    "maxExpiryDelay": -1,
    "maxDeliveryAttempts": 10,
    "pageCacheMaxSize": 5,
    "maxSizeBytes": 1,
    "pageSizeBytes": 1048576,
    "redeliveryDelay": 0,
    "redeliveryMultiplier": 1.0,
    "maxRedeliveryDelay": 0,
    "redistributionDelay": 0,
    "lastValueQueue": false,
    "sendToDLAOnNoRoute": false,
    "addressFullMessagePolicy": "PAGE",
    "slowConsumerThreshold": -1,
    "slowConsumerThresholdMeasurementUnit": "MESSAGES_PER_SECOND",
    "slowConsumerCheckPeriod": 5,
    "slowConsumerPolicy": "NOTIFY",
    "autoCreateJmsQueues": true,
    "autoDeleteJmsQueues": true,
    "autoCreateJmsTopics": true,
    "autoDeleteJmsTopics": true,
    "autoCreateQueues": true,
    "autoDeleteQueues": false,
    "autoCreateAddresses": true,
    "autoDeleteAddresses": false,
    "configDeleteQueues": "OFF",
    "configDeleteAddresses": "OFF",
    "maxSizeBytesRejectThreshold": -1,
    "defaultLastValueKey": "",
    "defaultNonDestructive": false,
    "defaultExclusiveQueue": false,
    "defaultGroupRebalance": false,
    "defaultGroupRebalancePauseDispatch": false,
    "defaultGroupBuckets": -1,
    "defaultGroupFirstKey": "",
    "defaultMaxConsumers": -1,
    "defaultPurgeOnNoConsumers": false,
    "defaultConsumersBeforeDispatch": 0,
    "defaultDelayBeforeDispatch": -1,
    "defaultQueueRoutingType": "MULTICAST",
    "defaultAddressRoutingType": "MULTICAST",
    "defaultConsumerWindowSize": 1048576,
    "defaultRingSize": -1,
    "autoDeleteCreatedQueues": false,
    "autoDeleteQueuesDelay": 0,
    "autoDeleteQueuesMessageCount": 0,
    "autoDeleteAddressesDelay": 0,
    "redeliveryCollisionAvoidanceFactor": 0.0,
    "retroactiveMessageCount": 0,
    "autoCreateDeadLetterResources": false,
    "deadLetterQueuePrefix": "DLQ.",
    "deadLetterQueueSuffix": "",
    "autoCreateExpiryResources": false,
    "expiryQueuePrefix": "EXP.",
    "expiryQueueSuffix": "",
    "enableMetrics": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `page-limit-bytes` and `page-limit-messages` settings are, in fact, reloaded and applied dynamically to matching addresses. However, there will be variability in how the settings are applied based on current runtime state. For example, these particular settings may not be reflected until the address has left and re-entered paging mode.

In your specific example if you run the `artemis consumer` command to consume all the messages (i.e. leave paging mode) and *then* send more than 100 messages it will succeed.

Also the fact that these settings are missing from `getAddressSettingsAsJSON` will be fixed in the next release via [ARTEMIS-3932](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3932)